# Why cant I read function out the switch statement

Tags: c

Program stores strings as string arrays. Strings can be names, addresses, etc.
• Program shows a selection screen that allows the user to enter strings (max. of 16, strings have a
maximum of 128 characters), remove a string from the database, view strings in database, search a
string, and quit the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void clearscreen()
{
    system("cls");
}

int main()
{
    int b1,b,c;
    char data[20]; 
    int number,a;

    do{
        clearscreen();
        printf("How many data do you want to store  ");
        scanf("%d",&number);

        for(a=1;a<=number;a++)
        {
            printf("Input your data %d_No:       ",a);
            scanf("%s",&data[a]);
        }

        printf("What action do you want to do\n [1]Remove data\n [2]View data\n [3]Search data\n[4] Quit");
        scanf("%d",&b1);

        switch(b1)
        {
            case 1:

                clearscreen();
                break;
            case 2:
                for(c=1;c=number;c++)
                {
                    printf("%d:%s",a,data[a]);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                return 0;
                break;
        }

        printf("\nDO you want to continue\n[1] YES\n [2] No   ");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        if (b==2)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    } while(b !=2);
}
```

The program is running but when I switch to 2 It cant read the int number, and char data
why is it? and what should I do?

Comment: You should format better your code, enable all warnings and debugging information in your compiler, try to write standard conforming code (notice that `<conio.h>` is not standard), and learn how to use your debugger, then use it step by step.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What is happening? - The for loop in case 2 looks odd: `for(c=1; c=number; c++)` - should it be <= or something?

Answer (score 2):

```
for(c=1;c=number;c++)
    printf("%d:%s",a,data[a]);
```

I see three problems here. The first is that you probably meant `c <= number`, based on your data entry loop.

The second is that you're using `a` as an array index rather than the `c` you should be using.

The last is that arrays are zero-based so `int a[20]` gives you `a[0]` thru `a[19]` inclusive. In other words, your loops should go from `0` to `number - 1` rather than `1` to `number`.

Answer (score 0):

in case 2 use `c` variable &  use `c<=number` instead of `c=number`

```
for(c=1;c<=number;c++)
                {
                    printf("%d:%s",c,data[c]);
                }
```